# Applying a tansig or tanh function on embedded.fi files

Tags: matlab, floating-point, neural-network

I was trying to apply a `tansig` or `tanh` function on my fixpointed data which I am using for my neural nework in MatLab, but when I use these functions on embedded.fi files, MatLab says that `tanh` or `tansig` function will not work on embedded.fi.

I am trying to set my neural network using fixpointed weights. I will really appreciate it if anyone has solution for that

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, there is no fixed-point version of `tanh` and `tansig` functions in Matlab. The complete list of functions that have fixed-point versions and are supported can be found here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/ug/fixed-point-run-time-library-support.html

Comment: Really appreciate it, but how can i use tansig on fixpoint values? I have to design my circuit with fixpoint values and tansig function.do i have to stimate tansig using mathematical equations?how?

Comment: I think that this link https://mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/examples/calculate-fixed-point-sine-and-cosine.html could be helpful for you.